# Convert List<string> into List<UInt32>

Tags: c#, list

I have a string with hexadecimal values, so I need to put the hex values in a `List<UInt32>`, so I use `string.Split()` to separate the values and make a string array, then I convert that string array into a `List<string>`, but how do I convert into the `List<UInt32>`? I investigated `CopyAll()`, but I don't know how exactly use it.

Here's the code:

```
string hex = "{0xa4, 0x23, 0x33} ";
List<string> stringvalue;
List<UInt32> uintvalue;
string[] separators1 = { "{", "}", ",", " ", "0x"};
string[] HEXData = hex.Split(separators1, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
stringvalue = HEXData.ToList();
```

Comment: You need an `int.Parse()` somewhere in a loop.

Comment: Please post a [mcve], which is some real code that can compile. Yours won't compile.

Comment: `hex.SplitIntoAnArrayOfIndividualHexStringsWithoutSeparators().Select(x => UInt32.Parse(x, NumberStyles.HexNumber)).ToList();`

Comment: @Will: wow, so you just implemented that in the .NET framework for this poor guy? You're awesome!

Comment: Well, he's got the split stuff down pat...

Comment: I think it was a joke, I'm detecting a joke. My jokedar may be off though...

Comment: @Will thanks for pointing it out. I've corrected my answer

Comment: How about using Regex to split the hex string
   `Regex.Matches(hex, @"0[xX][0-9a-fA-F]+")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to convert to INT and tell the convert function, that the input is in hex format:

```
uintvalue = stringvalue.Select(s => int.Parse(s,NumberStyles.HexNumber)).ToList();
```

Or (for UINT32)

```
uintvalue = stringvalue.Select(s => Convert.ToUInt32(s, 16)).ToList();
```

Comment: @Will adjusted my answer

Comment: May consider using ```TryParse``` in order to prevent exceptions.